# Remove height auto using css

Tags: html, css, height

I have images which have width and height in html but there is also a stylesheet affecting these images with height auto

How to reset/override this property using css so that the html height comes into effect?

Html:

```
<img src="..." width="350" height="150" />
```

Css:

```
img {
  height: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23uLp42n/5/)

More info:
I'm implementing img lazyload in an environment I don't fully control (PrestaShop eCommerce).
On document ready, I'm setting the img src to a transparent pixel but as the js-fiddle shows, the image comes squared althought it doesn't have the same width/height in html.
The height is following the width because of the height auto prop.
This leads to "jumping" and also to some bugs when a script sets the height style to the wrong value.

Comment: Note for people playing around with linked JSFiddle: comments starting with `//` are not valid in CSS, so the declarations you put in second `img` style won't count if you put them after the original comment.

Comment: Can you include a little bit more of the markup? Like a parent div, etc. Might be able to adjust some of these images the way.

Comment: If I'm correct in assuming that you don't want to manually override the heights *back* to their HTML originals using CSS, then I don't think that's possible.

Comment: In my opinion the generic declaration of an image tag without a class selector overriding the height is not the best practice. If anything .img-height-auto should define the styling and when auto height override is needed it should be added to the img tag such as  class="img-height-auto"

Comment: I was kinda certain that this is not possible with CSS but for all these years CSS never ceased to surprise me so I said let me take a shot at this :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - disabling width: auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29903427/1016716)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While this answer feels somewhat cheap, I truly believe it's the answer you're looking for...

---

**You can't.**

Once you've set a `height` on the `img` in CSS, the HTML declaration gets immediately overridden. There is no way further along in the CSS to then *ignore* that declaration and use the HTML-specified height, because things like *initial* refer to CSS-defined properties *([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value))*, not associated HTML attributes.

See this reference for [CSS Height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height), which lists all Property Values: <sup><sup>*Experimental/non-supported values ommitted</sup></sup>

> height: auto | *length* | % | inherit | initial

If you attempt to re-define the `height` of `img` using any of the above property values, they will not work - I've just tried each and every one to be sure.

- *`length`* and `%` require a defined height, which seems to be the exact thing you're trying to avoid
- `initial` will just grab the initial CSS declaration of `height: auto;`
- `inherit` doesn't have an ancestor to inherit from, therefore it falls back to the default of `auto`

---

Your only real choice is to override the height in CSS, either using in-line styles (as suggested by [Carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7987949/carter))...

```
<img style="height: 150px;" />
```

---

Or by applying selectors like ID's or classes...

```
<img id="my_image" />
```

```
#my_image {
    height: 150px;
}
```

---

Or, if you need to use JS to auto-generate the overrides, consider something like this jQuery solution:

```
$("img").each(function() {        //Loop through all images
    var $t = $(this);             //$t is the current iteration
    var ht = $t.attr("height");   //Get the HTML height
    ht = ht ? ht+"px" : "auto";   //If HTML height is defined, add "px" | Else, use "auto"
    $t.css("height", ht);         //Apply the height to the current element
});
```

This loops through all images on the page and applies a CSS height to match the HTML height. If there is no HTML height, it will use `height: auto;`.

Comment: Thank you, i'll accept this as I'm now certain of the limitation. I will read the  height property using js and force it using style and hope it doesn't cause any bugs with other script as I'm in an unpredictable environment (as detailed in the question)

Comment: @UnLoCo Appreciate it. I've edited my answer to include a jQuery solution in the event it helps you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use inline css to override your other css. The img height does not override the css because it's html so you need to use `<img src="..." width="350" style="height:150px;" />`

Comment: As I understood it, OP was trying to "ignore" the CSS height, rather than simply re-specifying. Again, this is only my interpretation, but in the event OP has 100 images that have set HTML heights, he wants to use those as overrides in one fell swoop. Like a CSS `height: ignore-CSS-and-use-HTML` property, for lack of a better explanation.

Comment: @Santi I thought that might be the case, but I didn't have enough rep to comment so I just went with this answer.

Comment: Understood, I suppose we'll see. Either way, your suggestion *is* an answer, OP may just have left the door open a bit more than intended. Then again, it could be exactly what he/she is looking for!

Comment: I vote up your answer fow now, I will provide more info about my case in the question

Comment: I aslo up-voted you because indeed it's a valid solution and one I have used for other reasons on many occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Best Practice is not to globally define all img tags with overriding height. I would if you can, change that declaration to:

```
img.auto-height {
  height: auto;
}
```

And anywhere you need to have an auto height on an image then add `class="auto-height"`

Comment: voted up but I don't control the environment unfortunately!

Comment: what a bummer :(

Answer (score 2):

You can override height with:

```
height: unset;
```

Browser support is [all except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value)

Comment: This doesn't work. It reverts the height to `initial` which as the answer above says gives it `height: auto`.

Comment: "all except IE"... simple solution http://www.ihateinternetexplorer.com/

Answer (score 1):

While it's not exactly removing, there's a couple other ways you could try and work around it.

- Adjust the height via the parent

`div img {
  height: 150px;
}`

- Or with a `pseudo-selector`

`img:nth-child(1n){
  height: 150px;
}`

```css
img:nth-child(1n){
  height: 150px;
}
img {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="width="350" height="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying that lazy loading to all your images, then you could set that image "auto" size only once the lazy magic is applied:

```
img:not(.lazy) {
  height: auto;
}
```

in the meantime the real img is loaded, html attribute height="X" will be applied, that is expected to be much more close to the real image dimensions.

Another hack that helps me avoid that shift effect is to use a base64 image placeholder with a ratio closer to the final images (normally a 2:1 will fit better in most of the cases than a 1:1 square pixel).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to J. Alba's answer, I've gone with:

```
img:not(.no-height-auto) {
  height: auto;
}
```

So, that means most images get height auto, which is what I normally want:

```
<!-- this gets height:auto -->
<img src="my-img.jpg" height="600" width="800" />
```

But if I *don't* want a particular image to have height auto, I add the class:

```
<!-- this gets height 600px from the attribute -->
<img src="my-img.jpg" class="no-height-auto" height="600" width="800" />
```